# Xdebug connection not working with PhpStorm and Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a problem debugging PHP with PhpStorm. I have container, and it is running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and my host machine is macOS 10.14.5. I added configuration to PhpStorm, but breakpoint is not hit.

So, this is my xdebug.ini configuration:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"
xdebug.remote_host = "192.168.1.144"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1

#  Enable the debugging on request
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_autostart = off

# enable logging
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

When I run `php -m -v`, I can see under Zend Modules that Xdebug is enabled/installed. My php version is PHP 7.1.32.

192.168.1.144 is the IP of my host machine. I also checked that PhpStorm is configured to listen on port 9000

[image: Xdebug settings]

When I created new configuration, I set `IDE key(session id)` as `XDEBUG_ECLIPSE`, also, when I defined server under configuration, host is correct (dummy.test), port is set to 80, and Debugger is set to Xdebug.

I also ran command `tail -f /tmp/xdebug.log`, and when I refreshed the page, there wasn't any new entry in the log file.

Any idea what am I missing? I set up breakpoint to one index function of xy controller and is not hit, I also enabled break at first line in PHP script.

[image: phpinfo]

Comment: can you please add Dockerfile?

Comment: phpstorm is not detecting  the ip

Comment: @myxaxa docker file is actually quite big (work project), if you could tell me what precisely would you like to see, I will be happy to show it. This is output of `docker ps` command:
`9771a8a1bad2        core_dev:0.1.12     "docker/php-apache/f…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour (healthy)   80/tcp, 4750/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                         core`

Comment: @shihab, do you mean that php storm is not detecting ip specified in configuration? URL for server in configuration is set to `dummy.test`, if I write that to browser, I get response, also, if I ping this url from terminal it is working, so why wouldn't php storm detect this?

Comment: @golobich just the part where you are copying fpm-configs. or can you just check is xdebug enabled with phpinfo()?

Comment: It will be easier if I just check with phpinfo :). And yes, I checked and xdebug is enabled. Will add image to original question

Comment: @myxaxa, I probably found the issue. In my phpinfo, I can see, that `xdebug.remote_host` is set to `host.docker.internal`. And idea how I can change this?

Comment: @golobich it's something only for mac as I can see - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Comment: Thank you, so apparently, this is not an issue :/

Comment: @golobich can you just add a hack into you /etc/hosts inside container and do an alias to your ip? before that check if ping is working with this `host.docker.internal`. I mean add a line in hosts: `192.168.1.144 host.docker.internal`

Comment: yes yes yes...it is working. apperently host.docker.internal resolved to different ip (192.168.65.2), when I added that entry to my host file, it started working. Please, post some summary as a answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @golobich I will try, but it's so ugly solution :)

Comment: I know, just let people know, that this is temporary solution. Issue here is that remote_host is wrong and it is pointing to wrong ip.

Comment: @golobich probably it's pointing on docker bridge ip. but I never used Mac. so someone with better experience should help :) glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, with help of the topic owner it was found that for Mac `host.docker.internal` is set [doc](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/)

as a hack-solution host ip was added to `/etc/hosts` inside docker container:
`host-ip host.docker.internal`

probably there should be a better solution :)